# add information to event in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm wondering how to add more information to an event embed in a button.

For example:

```
okButton = ttk.Button( content, text = 'OK' )
okButton.bind( "<Button-1>", browseFile )

def browseFile( event ):
    pass
```

When the button clicked, I want to pass the string parameter 'OK' to the function `browseFile`, what I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: why not just do something like, `myText = 'OK'` inside `browseFile`? Why do you need to pass it as a parameter?

Comment: I just want to use the same function call back for two button 'OK' and 'Cancel', so each button send a different event message to the function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `event` object has a `widget` member that identifies the widget that raised the event. You can get the text of that widget using the `cget` method:

```
def browseFile(event):
    buttonText = event.widget.cget("text")
    if buttonText == "OK":
        doSomeStuff()
```

Comment: Or I can decorate the object okButton with `okButton.myOwnStuff = 'text' ` so I can get later?

Comment: I don't see any documentation one way or the other about whether you can safely use custom attributes in that way. It works on my machine though, so it's probably fine.